# pandas dataframe - merging rows by substituting values with column value

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Apologies for the ambiguous title.

I have a dataset of students and I want to run a clustering algorithm on the students.

The dataset is structured such that there are more than one row per student, each with age, grade (9th, 10th, etc) a single class the student is taking and the final score in that class.

In pre-processing I apply pd.get_dummies to get one column for each class students are taking with a boolean value and the score column stays as is.

I want to merge the rows such that for each student I only have one row (because I want to cluster over students, not each row) and instead of 1 or 0 for each class, I want the final score of that class to appear in the class column and then eliminate the score column.

I will try to present an example:

```
Name, Age, Grade, Class, Score
John, 16, 9, Biology, 98
John, 16, 9, Algebra, 95
John, 16, 9, French, 96
```

Applying pd.get_dummies results in the following columns:

```
Name, Age, Grade, Class_Biology, Class_Algebra, Class_French, Score
```

I am interested in the following result:

```
Name, Age, Grade, Class_Biology, Class_Algebra, Class_French
John, 16, 9, 98, 95, 96
```

Is there a more efficient way than iterating over the rows and manually creating a new row in the dataframe for each student?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) + [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = (df.set_index(['Name','Age','Grade', 'Class'])['Score']
        .unstack()
        .add_prefix('Class_')
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)

   Name  Age  Grade  Class_Algebra  Class_Biology  Class_French
0  John   16      9             95             98            96
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Is there a way to do this without detailing the specific columns?

I didn't want to make a complex example, so apologies if this was relevant information - there are other columns that don't have to be transformed.  For example, participation in extra curriculars - suppose we have gymnastics, swimming and soccer.  With pd.get_dummies they transform to activity_gymnatics, etc. and they should remain as binary columns.

Comment: There is possible select column by positions only, change `(df.set_index(['Name','Age','Grade', 'Class'])['Score']` to `df = (df.set_index(df.columns[:4].tolist())[df.columns[4]]`.

Comment: I see you edited comment. Can you change your data with expected output?

Comment: Thank you! I see I was a little unclear in my example (made one up since I can't disclose true details).  A better example would be:

Comment: Prev comment messed up-
I have around 60 columns, only a few of which I want to convert to this format.  So far, pandas pivot_table is doing a good job (data looks similar to yours) but presents a different challenge I hope to sort out:

    'pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Name'], columns=['Score'], values=['Age','Grade']

                    Score                               Age                         Grade  
    Class   Algebra Biology French  Algebra Biology French Algebra Biology French
    Name
    John       95           98      96         16         16         16       9  9   9'

Comment: Thank you for upvote. It is not easy, because is necessary aggregate each column. So solution should be use `set_index` + `unstack` and then join all another columns. But then values rows from my solution are duplicated.

Comment: Btw, are data confidental?